# How to display multiple video from local directory in a QML Project?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to play a loop streaming video from local directory in my QML Project.

For now I'm using this code for playing one video only, but my goal is to play all the video from my local directory, Can I possibly do that?

```
  Video {
    id: video
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.rightMargin: 259
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: -18
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottomMargin: 57
    anchors.topMargin: 114
    //        position: 0
    //        x: 10
    autoPlay: true
    loops: MediaPlayer.Infinite
    source: "qrc:/Resources/Restaurant Video Ads Sample.mp4"
}
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-playlist.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `PlayList` to the `Video` and add all the videos there:

```
Video {
    id: video

    ...

    playlist: Playlist {
        id: playlist
        PlaylistItem { source: "qrc:/Resources/Restaurant Video Ads Sample.mp4"; }
        PlaylistItem { source: "qrc:/Resources/Restaurant Video Ads Sample2.mp4"; }
        ...
    }
}
```